# Dataframe.apply row type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types, type-hinting

Given a sample dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [4, 5, 6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

If the user wants to create a new column based on previous columns, they could create a function (it could also be a `lambda` function, but for this example a reguar function is used.

```
def calc_new_column(row):
    ''' creates new column based on values from other columns
    
    args:
        row: the rows of a pandas dataframe
    
    return: value that goes into each row of the new coulmn of the dataframe

    '''
    # print(type(row))

    if int(row['col1']) > 1:
        if int(row['col2']) <= 5:
            return 'in range'
    return 'out range'
```

Finally, the user can apply this function to all the rows on the dataframe creating the new column.

```
# the new column
df['col3'] = df.apply(calc_new_column, axis=1)
```

This successfully produces the new column. (output)

```
   col1  col2       col3
0     1     4  out range
1     2     5   in range
2     3     6  out range
```

If one does `type(row)` the result is `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`, but one cannot type hint to this.

So the question is, what is the `type` of the argument `row` that is input into the funciton (that one might indicate to the user with `type hinting` or in the `doc string`)?

Comment: it seems that obvious types that this arguement might be are `any` or `object`. Does this make sense ?

Comment: or is the type `pd.core.series.Series` as is stated in the `class` ?